# Why does Android Studio 3.1.3 and/or emulator start hundreds of instances of adb?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, adb, android-studio-3.0

Installed Android Studio 3.1.3 yesterday and built my app.  Now the emulator and/or Studio has started over 200 instances of adb on my machine.  I had to kill the emulator to get them to finally die.

[image: task manager showing adb]

Here's the full info on Android Studio:

- Android Studio 3.1.3
- Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 4, 2018
- JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- Windows Server 2016 10.0